# How to enrich cached DXA 2.0 custom PageModel with Localization data

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

When our custom (DXA 2.0 Java) `PageModel` gets loaded we add extra metadata. This extra data comes from `Localization` values. This works fine when the cache is disabled in `cd_client_conf.xml`.
But when the cache is enabled, `Localization` seems to be missing in the request.

This is the code we use in the `PageModel` to retrieve the `Localization`:

```
protected void retrieveLocalization() {
    RequestAttributes attributes = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    localization = (Localization) attributes.getAttribute(LOCALIZATION_ATTR, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
    assertSettingsAvailableInLocalization();
}
```

This worked fine in DXA 1.8, but not in DXA 2.0

Is it possible to retrieve `Localization` for a cached `PageModel`?